# Stop Processing Page After Exception Is Caught

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

**TL;DR**

In C#/ASP.NET, how can I stop processing the page after an exception is caught?

**Details**

I have four try/catch blocks that attempt to pull data from a MS SQL database, and I have created a `ThrowException()` method to handle exceptions. In that method, I am writing the exception text to a database table, so I thought I should have a try/catch there, also, and write out *that* exception to the screen (something obviously terrible has happened if we get here). But I am getting four copies of this text to the screen; how can I stop processing the page after one call to the catch block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpApplication.CompleteRequest` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) is the recommended way to end a request.  Unlike `HttpResponse.End`, it does not throw a `ThreadAbortException`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you can get a hold of the `HttpResponse` object in the exception handler, you could clear/flush the response data and then write your error, followed by `HttpResponse.End()` to terminate further execution.

One way to get a hold of the response is `HttpContext.Current.Response`

Note that `HttpResponse.End()` uses exceptions for flow control, and is somewhat of an anti-pattern. It should work for your situation, however.

Answer (score 1):

`Response.End()` will stop execution, however make sure you are also releasing your database object(s).